# Set a variable in jinja by querying a list

Tags: flask, jinja2

So, lets say I have a route like following

```
@app.route('/get_list/<int:q>')
def get_list(q):
   return [1,2,3, q]
```

and in html, I want to get this list (without passing thru template)

I am trying to do something like

```
{% set variables = "url_for('get_list', q=1)" %}
<ul>
{% for var in variables%}
<li> {{var}} </li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>
```

But, well the set variables is wrong.
Is there a way to query the server and get those variables rather than passing thru the "render_template" ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should [jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify) your data.

Although, I don't understand what do you want to retrieve from your array, I retrieve only one value passed through GET request like so:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/get_list/<int:q>')
def get_list(q):
    dummy_data = [44, 55, 33]

    # dummy_data.index(q) return position in array of q value
    # so if you pass 55, it will return 1
    result_from_query = dummy_data[dummy_data.index(q)]

    return jsonify(result_from_query)
```